# Django Form Not Validating my Date fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Search form that includes the query box, some checkbox items, and a start and end date. I am getting my information when I enter a query, so I know it is performing the search_results action, but the start and end date is not getting validated at all. I have yet to add the code to handle the start and end date in my results, but the issue is there is no client side validation happening on the form.

My form looks like this:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):

    q = forms.CharField(max_length=64,required=False)
    service_choices = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=CustomUser.SERVICE_CHOICES,
        )
    start_date = forms.DateField(required=False)
    end_date = forms.DateField(required=False)
```

I tried using Class Based View, but did not get any fields at all, so I
tried using a function based view to get my search criteria.

The view looks like:

```
def get_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    return render(request, 'get_search.html', {'form':form})
```

My template is:

```
<!-- templates/get_search.html -->
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Search{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <br><br>
  <TABLE BORDER="0" WIDTH="100%">
        <TR>
        <TD ALIGN="Left"><B>Track X - search</B></TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Center"><B>User:&nbsp;{{ user }}</B></TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Right"><B>Service:&nbsp;{{ user.service }}</B></TD>
        </TR>
  </TABLE>


  <form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get"">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <TABLE BGCOLOR="#66CCCC" Border="2" WIDTH="100%">
    <TR>
      <TD ALIGN="Left" WIDTH="100">&nbsp;&nbsp;Services:</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Right">Search expression:</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Left">
            {{ form.q }}
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Search TrackX</button>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD WIDTH="100"> {{ form.service_choices }} </TD>
      <TD COLSPAN="2" ALIGN="Center"> Start Date:&nbsp;{{ form.start_date }}&nbsp;&nbsp;
      End Date:&nbsp;{{ form.end_date }}</TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
  </form>
{% else %}
    <p>You are not logged in</p>
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a> |
    <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

The Search_results view just uses the query to build some Q Filter
queries, and it seems to be working correctly.
It originally used a GET Method, and was passing the parameters into the search results view just fine.  It just doesn't validate the dates (or anything else I assume) before passing the parameters into the view.
Can anyone tell me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

As I see on the view that your posted, you are not actually checking if the form is valid, you can do that by using:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   form = SearchForm(request.POST)
   form.is_valid()
```

This method will validate all your fields, and return the boolean value representing if its valid or not.

Comment: Well that doesn't seem to change anything.... I added the above code after my form=SearchForm().  Still no validation. Also, this is a GET method - not Post...

Comment: I'm sorry, Im not quite getting what you are trying to do then. If you are trying to validate the form in the client-side, you must use JavaScript. But I personally recomend to let Django do all the validations, in the server-side. To do that you must make a POST request with your form data to your view, and then validate the fields as I explained above.

Comment: I have tried this a couple of ways. My original form had just the search query bar, and it was a "GET" method form which called the search_results view which processed the query. When I added the start and end dates I noticed there was no validation happening. In my other forms the validation works fine, but they don't have actions and they are POST methods.  Are you saying a GET method form cannot do any validation on the Django side? or maybe I should have the action be "" and then process the form and redirect? Tried changing to POST but then I get a 405 - Method not allowed.

Comment: The thing is, you must find a way to pass your values to the the form, the way I explained above is using a POST request, but you can also use GET, as long as you pass the GET parameters to the form, as a dictionary, and then call form.is_valid(). Probably `form = SearchForm(request.GET)` and then `form.is_valid()` will work, as long as you pass the GET parameters with the same name as the form fields. To find out if the form is valid, use the boolean value returned from the is_valid() function.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean... I dont know if we are on this same page about the view(s).  The get_Search template calls the Search_results template after I click search. It passes the parameters to search results. Search results doesn't have the form at all, only get_search has the form values.